# What is "the DataStax Enterprise user name"?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am trying to use the Beeline terminal client. Reading the Datastax Beeline documentation, [it states](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaHivBeeline.html)

> Enter the DataStax Enterprise user name.

and later

> Enter the password.

What username/password is this? Is it a username related to internal authentication? What if a cluster does not have internal authentication enabled? It doesn't seem to be stored in configuration files:

```
$ grep -r user /etc/dse/hive
/etc/dse/hive/hive-log4j.properties:hive.log.dir=/tmp/${user.name}
/etc/dse/hive/hive-site.xml:    <value>cfs:///user/hive/warehouse</value>
/etc/dse/hive/hive-exec-log4j.properties:hive.log.dir=/tmp/${user.name}
/etc/dse/hive/hive-env.sh.template:# the Hive installation (so that users do not have to set environment variables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have DSE, you should have received an email from `DataStax Enterprise Registration` that would include your `username and password`